# What is the best way to get the location in android every 5 sec

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

what is the best way and bestpower-saving mode to get the following things in Android with LocationListener every 5 secounds:

1. Location (Latitude, Longitude)
2. Accuracy
3. Altitude
4. Speed
5. Bearing
6. ...

I tried this (LocationListener):

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   // ...Code...
}
```

But this only update if Location changed but I need every 5 sec and only there. Maybe someone can show me an example.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: if the location does not change, just use the same as previously...

Comment: But if the location change there is update befor this 5 sec.

Comment: did you read the doc for `requestLocationUpdate`? did you not see the `minTime` parameter? "minTime  long: minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds"

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. The anser from Alex Shutov works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rxJava's method Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.Seconds). ...
and ubsubscribe from it when updates are no longer needed. 
In event handling (subscribe()) method poll location manually.

```
Subscription pollingConnection = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(t -> {
                    // get all your readings manually (it is executed in background because of
                    //  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    return  t;
                })
                .subscribe(t -> {
                }, e -> {
                });

        // call pollingConnection.unsubscribe(); when update is no longer needed
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample??